# outer measure question

Tags: real-analysis

Let E have finite outer measure. Show that there is an $ F_{\sigma}$ set F and $ G_{\delta }$ set G such that $ F \subseteq E \subseteq G$ and $ m^*(F) = m^*(E) = m^*(G)$.

I have already shown that $ E \subseteq G$ and $ m^*(E) = m^*(G)$. But don't know how to prove the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is an $F_\sigma$ set $F \subset E$ with $m^*(F) = m^*(E)$.  Since $E \subset G$, $m^*(E) = m^*(G) < \infty$ and $F,G$ are measurable, this implies that $$m^*(G \setminus F) = m^*(G) - m^*(F) = 0.$$ Since $G \setminus E \subset G \setminus F$ you get $m^*(G \setminus E) = 0$, implying $E$ is measurable.

In short, it isn't true unless $E$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $E$ is measurable here.

**Hint:** Suppose $G_n$ is an open with $E \subset G_n$ and $G = \bigcup G_n$.  Try to find $F_n$ such that $(F_n)^c$ are open with $E^c \subset (F_n)^c$ and $F = \bigcap F_n$.